# Dropped Pin not pushing location data to parse using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a map and two buttons. The map auto locates the user and if he or she pushes button 1 it saves the current location to parse. That works fine. However if you navigate elsewhere on the map and drop a pin I expect for that location to be pushed to parse when you tap button 2 but it just pushes the current location.

I think I'm close i just need a little bit of help getting it to work.

Here is my code

```
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.mapView.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "mapLongPress:")
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1.5
    self.mapView.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)

var mapChangedFromUserInteraction = false

 func mapViewRegionDidChangeFromUserInteraction() -> Bool {
    let view = self.mapView.subviews[0]
    //  Look through gesture recognizers to determine whether this region change is from user interaction
    if let gestureRecognizers = view.gestureRecognizers {
        for recognizer in gestureRecognizers {
            if( recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began || recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended ) {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
    let location = locations.last

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
func mapLongPress(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer){
    print("its done")

    let touchedAt = recognizer.locationInView(self.mapView)
    let touchedAtCoordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D = mapView.convertPoint(touchedAt, toCoordinateFromView: self.mapView)
    let newPin = MKPointAnnotation()
    newPin.coordinate = touchedAtCoordinate
    mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
    mapView.showsUserLocation = false
    mapView.addAnnotation(newPin)
}


@IBAction func photographer(sender: AnyObject, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    let loc =  manager.location!.coordinate
    let actualLocation = PFGeoPoint(latitude:loc.latitude,longitude:loc.longitude)
    let object = PFObject(className:"User")
    object["Location"] = actualLocation
    object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (_success:Bool, _error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if _error == nil
        {
            // yay its saved
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func buyer(sender: AnyObject, forEvent event: UIEvent) {

}
```

Comment: Could you maybe just include the code that deals with you question, I am a little confused about what everything does.

Comment: that is all the code that deals with maps, i left everything else out

Comment: @IBAction func buyer...is button # 2, i don't know what to put in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly you could do something like this.

```
 //this would be an optional property that could have a value if there was a pin that was dropped
 var locationsOfPinDrop: PFGeoPoint?

func mapLongPress(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer){

    let touchedAt = recognizer.locationInView(self.mapView)
    let touchedAtCoordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D = mapView.convertPoint(touchedAt, toCoordinateFromView: self.mapView)
    let newPin = MKPointAnnotation()
    newPin.coordinate = touchedAtCoordinate
    mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
    mapView.showsUserLocation = false
    mapView.addAnnotation(newPin)

    //I added this line... It will store the last location that was pressed using the long press.
    self.locationOfPinDrop = PFGeoPoint(latitude:touchedAtCoordinate.latitude, touchedAtCoordinate:loc.longitude)
}

@IBAction func buyer(sender: AnyObject, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
     if let location = locationOfPinDrop {
          //there is a coordinate there, it is not nil.
            let user = PFObject(className:"User")
            user["Location"] = location
            user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (_success:Bool, _error:NSError?) -> Void in
                 if _error == nil {
                      //This resets the locationOfPinDrop to nil now that it is saved.
                      self.locationOfPinDrop = nil
                 }
            }
       }
}
```

I am having a little bit of a hard time understanding your question, however I believe that my answer solves it. I simply create a stored property of `locatationOfPinDrop`, then, when the user has a long press, `locationOfPinDrop` is set to that coordinate. Now, when button 2 `buyer` is pressed, this location gets updated.

If I understood something wrong, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Make a property called lastPin or something that you set to be equal to the newPin. Then, when you call your buyer function, do basically what you're doing in the other function, except instead of using myLocation, use the marker's location.

Comment: could you please elaborate just a tad on the last part. Im trying do it but im getting errors

Comment: I don't know enough about swift syntax to write it for you, but the markers should have a position or location property that has a coordinate that you can get the latitude and longitude from. Check the documentation for the SDK and you should be able to find it.